# Using javascript ".replace" to format a phone number?

Tags: javascript

I have a phone number stored in a variable and I want to format this number to include the country code. Right now I have this:

```
var PhoneNumber = 07xxxxxxxx;
NewNumber = PhoneNumber.replace("0", "+46");
```

It works great, however, currently it replaces any 0 in the number.
It must only replace the 0 on the beginning of the number. For example, if the number in the variable looks like this 750xxxxxxx then it must not replace the zero, but if the 0 is at the beginning of the number (like so 07xxxxxxxx) then it must replace it.

Comment: Can you update your code to show what you're *actually* working with? This snippet throws a syntax error - please also review the guidance on providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: @esqew it seriously doesn't make sense to post my entire code. The rest of my code has nothing to do with the actual question. The rest of my code deals with form data and it is not applicable here.

Comment: @Shtarley I'm not sure where I've indicated that you need to post your "*entire code*" - I've merely suggested that you review and update the snippet you've included here as it contains invalid syntax in the first line (specifically an unencapsulated string).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var phone = '0700000000';
var newPhone = phone.replace(/^0/, '+46 ');
console.log('new phone', newPhone);
```

It's the `^` that specifies you want to match the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to use [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if the leading character is a `0`, then concatenating the `+46` string to the front of `PhoneNumber` while removing the leading `0` with [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```js
var PhoneNumber = "07xxxxxxxx";
var NewNumber;

if (PhoneNumber.startsWith("0")) {
  NewNumber = "+46" + PhoneNumber.substring(1);
  console.log(NewNumber);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a regular expression (regex)

Assumed, that your number always starts with a zero you could use this

```
var PhoneNumber = "0781597515" //pseudo number
var Newnumber = PhoneNumber.replace(/0/, "+46");
```

Comment: This will not work to OP's spec if the string does not in fact start with a `0` - it will find the first `0` in the `PhoneNumber` variable and replace that with `+46` - [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/35vb7qsp/). @inorganik's answer above shows how to use the `^` RegExp token to properly indicate that only a *leading* zero should be replaced.